# How to inject an attribute using spring in a type handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, typehandler

I'm setting up an application which uses `mybatis` to map objects to/from the database.

In my mybatis file, I use a `typehandler` to map one of the objects being sent to the database.

In the typeHandler, I am injecting an attribute using spring `@resource`.

However, when the `typehandler` is called, the injected property is always `null`.

From my research, I have discovered that `mybatis` sets its configuration before spring loads. That means the bean is cannot be injected into the handler as it is created after.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Should let spring manage customized type handler, like this:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="typeHandlers">
      <array>
        <bean class="com.example.YourCustomTypeHandler">
          <!-- inject -->
          <property name="property" ref="bean"/>
        </bean>
      </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```